# How to have ellipses clickable to show the next sequence of pagination

Tags: pagination, datatables

In jQuery DataTables pagination control is displayed like:

<kbd>1</kbd> ... <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> ... <kbd>14</kbd>

How can I make the ellipses clickable so if it's clicked it will show:

<kbd>1</kbd> ... <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> ... <kbd>14</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the code below:

```
$('#example').on('init.dt draw.dt', function(e, settings){
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

   $('.dataTables_paginate span a:first + .ellipsis', api.table().container()).replaceWith(
       $('<a class="paginate_button">...</a>').on('click', function(e){ 
           api.page('previous').draw('page'); 
           e.preventDefault();
       })
   ); 

   $('.dataTables_paginate .ellipsis', api.table().container()).replaceWith(
       $('<a  class="paginate_button">...</a>').on('click', function(e){
           api.page('next').draw('page');
           e.preventDefault();
       })
   );        
});

var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

where `example` is ID of your table.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aw0nxmeb/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Hi, but in your case, it pretty much the same as previous or next button. How to make it so it jump to the next sequence, so if I'm in page 4 or 5 or 6, once I press the ellipses next, it will show the next sequence 789, and open the page 8 (the middle one) ?

Comment: @Harts, you can add that logic in the click functions above to go to required page number instead of `previous`/`next` while using [`page.info()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info%28%29) to retrieve information about table pagination.