# Datatable Pagination Ellipses - I want to be able to click on the elipses and show next three sequence of numbers

Tags: datatables, pagination

in jQuery DataTables pagination control is displayed like:

1 ... 4 5 6 ... 14

How can I make the ellipses clickable so if it's clicked it will show:

1 ... 7 8 9 ... 14

The datatable configuration is below. It is possible to have two different ellipses and we do not have issues with that. We want to be able to click those ellipsis.

```
 < ... 7 8 9 ... > if you click on ellipsis after 9 we want to display    
 < ... 10 11 12 ... > with page 10 selected

 < ... 7 8 9 ... > if you click on ellipsis before 7 we want to display
 < ... 4 5 6 ... > with page 6 selected.

Datatable settings.
table.DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "pageLength": 5,
        "stripeClasses": [],
        "dom": "tp",
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "first": "<i class=\"fas fa-step-backward\">",
                "previous": "<i class=\"fas fa-chevron-left\">",
                "next": "<i class=\"fas fa-chevron-right\">",
                "last": "<i class=\"fas fa-step-forward\">"
            },
            "aria": {
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "First Page",
                    "previous": "Previous Page",
                    "next": "Next Page",
                    "last": "Last Page"
                }
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Thank you!!

Comment: A couple of questions about this: (1) What configuration are you using which results in you seeing two (or maybe more) ellipses in the pagination? One ellipsis - yes, with sufficient data and the right [paging type](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType). I have never seen more than one. And (2) Can you clarify why you may want this - because I don't think it's possible; but depending on the "why", there may be other approaches. Can you [edit] your question? Thank you!

Comment: @andrewjames, I have updated the question, please let me know if that makes it clearer.

Comment: Maybe it's only a minor point, but I never see _two_ sets of ellipses - only one. Your notes suggest you are seeing something I have never seen before.

Comment: I understand what you want to do - but my question is: why? I am fairly sure what you want to do is not possible (unless you start rewriting the paging display logic inside DataTables) - so, understanding the _why_ may help me to suggest alternatives.

Comment: we are using two different plugins, what we are trying to do is mimic the functionality and display between the two so even if we are using two different plugins to the end user the experience of using the pagination would be the same. There was a same question posted five years ago .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772041/how-to-have-ellipses-clickable-to-show-the-next-sequence-of-pagination.
I tried to add to that but i was not allowed to add comments so had to start a new thread

Comment: In your case, do you want to actually navigate to a new page when the ellipsis is clicked (which can be done based on the code in that older question), or do you want to only change the display of the pagination data? I assume it's the latter (no navigation).